# Elasticsearch - boosting specific documents in every search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm very new to Elasticsearch. I'm using it to filtering and also boosting some fields at query time. This is the code part for boosting and filtering:

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "multi_match": {
              "type": "best_fields",
              "query": "exampleKeyword",
              "fields": [
                "exampleField1^0",
                "exampleField2^50",
                "exampleField3^10",
                "exampleField4^10",
                "exampleField5^5"                  
              ],
              "boost": 50
            }
          }]
      }
    }
  ],
  "filter": [
    {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "bla": {
                      "value": ""
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }, {
            "term": {
              "active": {
                "value": "true"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "closingDate": {
                "gte": "201710310000",
                "lte": "999912312359"
              }
            }
          },
```

Now I want to boost some specific documents. I'll give an array of integers for  example Field6 and if my search results contain the elements of the array, these documents should get boosted with, I dont know, 100 to my scale.

How can I do this? Finally I dont want to expand the result set. Just want to boost more the desired ids if results contain these ids.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html for that with a filter and different `weight` for each filter. And the filter itself should probably be an [`ids` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-ids-query.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `function_score` you can do something around these lines:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "function_score": {
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "multi_match": {
                      "type": "best_fields",
                      "query": "bla",
                      "fields": [
                        "exampleField1^0",
                        "exampleField2^50",
                        "exampleField3^10",
                        "exampleField4^10",
                        "exampleField5^5"
                      ],
                      "boost": 50
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "functions": [
              {
                "filter": {
                  "ids": {
                    "values": [
                      1,
                      5
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "weight": 10
              }
            ],
            "score_mode": "max",
            "boost_mode": "multiply"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "bla": {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "active": {
                    "value": "true"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "closingDate": {
                    "gte": "201710310000",
                    "lte": "999912312359"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adrei, i'll try this asap. But i heard that using functions for boosting is bad for performance. Do you agree with that? If so what should be the better solution for performance because there are 20 query/seconds for 70.000 documents and i'll be using this new implemantation for this system.

Comment: It's an added aspect to a query, and it's additional cycles that ES needs for that. But I haven't heard of functions not being recommended, like it's the case for scripts for example. Scripts are good, indeed, but if you can do it differently, it's recommended.

Comment: Maybe you could also add another statement to the `should` section where you can use the `ids` query directly. The scores of the two statements under `should` should be combined, but you'll not be able to control how much the score of the `ids` will weigh in the overall query.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I said before im a newbie at elastic. So i couldnt figure out how to implement your solution to mine because there are already some filters (i ve edited the original code block). Can you show me the way to both keep these filters and add the new filter for boosting?

Comment: Updated the query.